# Styling CheckBox and showing content by Label not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide a checkbox and use it's label to check or uncheck it. I tried various ways like display:none, visibility:hidden, but none worked. Please help me out

my code:

```
$('.start').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'tags',
        method: 'get',
        success: function(data){
            var items = '';
            $.each(data,function(i,item){
                // checkbox for tags
                var tag = "<label for=tag[] class = 'btn tag_label'>"+ "<input type = checkbox name =tag[] value = "+item.tag_id+"class = tag_checkbox>" + item.tag_name+"</label>";
                $('.modal_tags').append(tag);

                $('.tag_label').click(function(){
                    $(this).toggleClass('tag_label_clicked');
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Css

```
.tag_label{
    border: 1px;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    border-color:#000000;
}

.tag_label:hover{
    background-color: #F7CD1F;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 900 !important;
    transition: 0.1s linear;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.tag_label_clicked{
    background-color: #F7CD1F;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 900 !important;
    transition: 0.1s linear;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.tag_checkbox{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: Can you give us an example of the html you are using as well?  What is the final effect you are trying to go for?  You don't need jquery just to check and uncheck a hidden checkbox.

Comment: Example? All i am doing is making a modal to choose preferences. a checkbox has a label with it. I want to hide checkbox and when label is clicked checkbox get selected. I am unable to do both. except this i have a toogle effect on my label like when someone click , label changes to yellow

Comment: The `for` attribute of the label needs to refer to the _id_ of an input element, not a name. But ids need to be unique within a document, so you’d have to be careful when generating these elements in a loop. Or you leave out the `for` attribute altogether here - if the input field is wrapped inside the label, it isn’t necessary.

Comment: @misorude, okay.. Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it.Thankyou so much

Comment: Thanks buddy, you solved my half problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult without the HTML... But you're hiding a checkbox and trying to check it?

Add a style to the checkbox such as

```
style="opacity:0;"
```

Or go a step further and use;

```
style="position:absolute; opacity:0; left:99999px;"
```

Also, check and uncheck it with;

```
$('.tag_checkbox').prop('checked', true);
$('.tag_checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

**EDIT**

Based on the original question, I'm not sure why this answer hasn't been selected!

Here's a  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y4dfj2oc/) with 2 checkboxes.  One hidden, one not and both with the label clickable so the checkboxes can be enabled with Jquery or with a click of the label.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . It worked.. But after this, the                 $('.tag_label').click(function(){
                    $(this).toggleClass('tag_label_clicked');
                });
 stopped working

Comment: Thankyou for help, i solved that. Took the toogle function out of each().

Answer (score 0):

Try with css

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none !important
}
```